# How to leave the remote desktop user session in Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: remote-desktop, microsoft-powerpoint, session, windows-server-2012-r2, asp

I'm having a problem in ASP.NET opening the  Microsoft PowerPoint Component when the Windows Server doesn't have an RDC (Remote Desktop Connection) Active User Session.

My question is how do I leave the RDC user session active in the Windows Server?

Below image was in a Remote Desktop running Windows Server 2003, showing the popup to choose which existing session I want to login and use. I want to set it up like this in Windows Server 2012. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Why is simply disconnecting (without logging out) insufficient?

Answer (score 0):

1. Login as administrator account in RDC.

   - Run cmd
   - Type mstsc /v:serverName /admin then hit enter.
2. Find the session # of the RDP-TCP session name

   - Run cmd (RDP Client)
   - Type tasklist or query session then hit enter. This will show all the running processes.
     On the 3rd column you will see the session #.

     - Type tscon session# /dest:console then hit enter. You will receive this pop-up message "Your Remote Desktop Has Ended"
       Ex: tscon 2 /dest:console